# 'fastboot boot' command doesn't work?

Tags: android, debugging, kernel, fastboot

I have compiled my kernel and I want to test it.

I used

```
fastboot boot zImage
```

but this command booted my old kernel. Why?

I have created and flashed boot.img with ramdisk from old kernel, but it doesn't boot. Is there any way to debug boot process without UART?

Greetings, Michal.

Edit:

I found solution. Before executing boot command, first I have to execute erase boot.

But I get boot loop :( Is there any way to read logs when I can't boot?

I really would like to make this kernel bootable. I will be glad for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the adb daemon starts so your are able to take logs.

So you can try to take log via adb

```
adb shell
logcat > log.txt
```

Also you can try this:

```
adb shell
cat /proc/kmsg > /sdcard/log.txt
```

In the first situation I suppose you will get only kernel outputs because android hasn't boot. But if the adb daemon hasn't been initilized then you can't take a log.

Answer (score -1):

Did you type your fastboot comand correctly?

It should be:

```
fastboot flash boot fileyouwishtoflash
```

Comment: There is such command: boot <kernel> [ <ramdisk> ] download and boot kernel